# UItableview and Keyboard with previous and next button scrolling issue - iPhone

Tags: ios, uitableview, keyboard, scrollview

Here I have a tableView on a scrollView. Each row contains a textField. Next button is ok(view animating properly on upword) but when I press on previous button on keyboard, I have to show down the view one by one according to the textField. How can I solve this? I have to do it in many views. Please help me as soon as possible. I badly need it. May be I'm doing wrong somewhere. Sorry for my language problem. Sample code may be helpful.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636532/300292). The library is simple to use--just drop it into your project and subclass its classes as opposed to `UIScrollView` or `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try the below method to scroll your tableview up and down based on which text field is selected, write this code in textfield delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  // calculate the nsindexpath based on the textfield which is selected

 //- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;

[yourtableview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:calcutaedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UIScrollViewPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

Hope it will help you